# 401 From MWAA Airflow Environment When Attempting To Run A DAG

Tags: python, python-requests, airflow, mwaa, airflow-api

## Description

When attempting to make calls to a Managed Amazon Airflow instance I was not able to make API calls to the airflow environment despite being able to generate a CLI token from `aws mwaa create-cli-token`. Why am I getting a FORBIDDEN error here?

## Console and Code

### Code

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def run_dag(
        environment_name: str,
        airflow_conn_info: AirflowConnectionInfo,
        dag_to_run: str,
        target_date: datetime) -> Callable:
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': airflow_conn_info.cli_token,

    }
    trigger_body = {
        "conf": {},
        "execution_date": target_date.isoformat(),
    }
    if not dag_to_run:
        dag_to_run = f"{carrier_name}_dag"

    base_url = f"https://{airflow_conn_info.hostname}/api/v1/dags/{dag_to_run}"
    trigger_dag_url = f"{base_url}/dagRuns"
    # TODO: Add some sort of check to ensure a DAG isn't disabled OR add a call
    #       to enable the DAG. For now we're just going to assume it's enabled.
    trigger_response = requests.post(
        trigger_dag_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(trigger_body))
    if trigger_response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(f"{trigger_response}")

    dag_run_status_url = f"{base_url}/{trigger_response.json()['dag_id']}"
    status_body = {}

    task_instances_status_url = f"{base_url}/dagRuns/{trigger_response.json()['dag_id']/taskInstances}"
    task_instances_body = {}

    status_response = requests.get(
        dag_run_status_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(status_body))

    if status_response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(f"{trigger_response}")
    # Derived from
    # https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/state.py
    terminal_states: List[str] = ["success", "failed"]
    # TODO: Add a timeout to this while loop.
    while (trigger_response.status_code == 200
            and trigger_response.json()["state"] not in terminal_states):
        # TODO: Add some sort of console output to show what task instance we're
        #       on and the state of that current task instance.
        status_response = requests.get(
            dag_run_status_url,
            headers=headers,
            data=json.dumps(status_body))

        task_instances_response = requests.get(
            task_instances_status_url,
            headers=headers,
            data=json.dumps(task_instances_body))
        breakpoint()
```

### Failing Run PDB

```
(Pdb) base_url
'https://{a_string}.c46.us-east-1.airflow.amazonaws.com/api/v1/dags/fedex_dag'
(Pdb) trigger_response.json()
{'detail': None, 'status': 401, 'title': 'Unauthorized', 'type': 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/Unauthenticated'}
(Pdb) headers
{'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '{secret}'}
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: The API is turned off by default. This is not explicitly stated anywhere. You should use the `https://YOUR_HOST_NAME/aws_mwaa/cli` endpoint unless you want to enable the full API.

When I was reading the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/call-mwaa-apis-cli.html) around generating a CLI token what was not clear to me is that the `aws_mwaa/cli` endpoint that AWS adds to the MWAA is the endpoint that they want you to use. This is explained in the [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/amazon-mwaa-user-guide.pdf) but not in any of the website documentation making it very unclear to me.

There is a `AmazonMWAAFullApiAccess` which sounds like it grants access to the full API if you have access to a role with the policy but i have not tested this yet.